# PackageMaker differentiate between PPC and Intel

Tags: macos, intel, packagemaker, powerpc

Okay, so, I'm making an installer package for Mac OS X. I have it place a driver file onto the system, but there's no Universal version of the driver. How can I make the Installer drop a different file depending on whether the computer is a PowerPC or and Intel? I checked the "Requirements" but the closest it would let me get is to require certain processor speeds or Mac OS X version numbers. Is there a way to require certain architectures as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Result of Sysctl` with `hw.cputype` (PPC = 18 and Intel = 7).

[image: Result of Sysctl]

CPU types:

```
#define CPU_TYPE_MC680x0   ((cpu_type_t) 6)
#define CPU_TYPE_X86       ((cpu_type_t) 7)
#define CPU_TYPE_MC98000   ((cpu_type_t) 10)
#define CPU_TYPE_HPPA      ((cpu_type_t) 11)
#define CPU_TYPE_ARM       ((cpu_type_t) 12)
#define CPU_TYPE_MC88000   ((cpu_type_t) 13)
#define CPU_TYPE_SPARC     ((cpu_type_t) 14)
#define CPU_TYPE_I860      ((cpu_type_t) 15)
#define CPU_TYPE_POWERPC   ((cpu_type_t) 18)
```